# How to skip a command if already exist in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have just started my hands on Ansible and trying some stuff on my own. I am running the below code:

```
---
- hosts: test-server
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: install java 8
    apt: name=openjdk-7-jdk update-cache=yes force=yes
  - name: add group
    command: addgroup hadoop
```

and getting the below error:-

> fatal: [10.150.0.3]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["addgroup", "hadoop"], "delta": "0:00:00.033669", "end": "2017-12-08 12:50:15.342671", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2017-12-08 12:50:15.309002", "stderr": **"addgroup: The group `hadoop' already exists."**, "stderr_lines": ["addgroup: The group 'hadoop' already exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
>   to retry, use: --limit @/root/hdp1.retry

I can go ahead and remove the group 'hadoop' and try the code again and it will be succeeded. But I want to make some condition in the code so that if the group already exists that step will be ignored. I have researched on it and found we could use some stat_result like `when: stat_result.stat.exists == False`. But I am not sure how to incorporate it in the code.

Answer (score 9):

This is **not** how you should write Ansible code.

Ansible is a declarative language and you should use a native [module `group`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/group_module.html) which provides idempotence:

```
- name: Ensure 'hadoop' group exists
  group:
    name: hadoop
    state: present
```

This way you don't have to check anything. The same task will either create a new group (status `changed`) or report that the group already exists (status `ok`). The state after executing will be the same: group `hadoop` is present.

<sup>Unfortunately not every action you want to perform has been implemented as native modules, that's why `command` module exists. But it should be used as a last resort.</sup>

Comment: Nice answer. Perhaps add a short explanation to idempotence or a link to an explanation since it may be a new term for users new to devops.